# Flutter: same deep link for web and mobile app

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

I have a mobile and web Flutter app which is deployed on web at `myhost`.

I want to have a deeplink of the type `/match/123` to redirect the user directly to the match page for match 123.

When I had only the mobile version I had Firebase dynamic link URL prefix at `myhost/link` and I would build a deep link using the rest API to bring the user to `myhost/match/123` and it all worked fine: if the app was installed, it would bring the user to the match page, if the app is not installed I would redirect to a static landing page. The deep link looks like `myhost/link/<randomly_generated_link_id>`

However now that I have the webapp I would like to use the same link in web and mobile.
For example if the user is on web at `myhost/match/123` and he copy-paste this link on mobile the webapp will be open (not the app) since the URL prefix is not the one specified in Firebase Dynamic Links.

How can I achieve that `myhost/match/123` works as follows:

- on mobile: go to match page on app if app installed else go to webapp
- on web: go to webapp

?